# angular: checking each country and add value 0 to empty field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to dynamically create empty objects with value 0 for each countries wrt its months(all months).
plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZsMpdFXMvGHZR5Qbs0m?p=preview

Currently each country has 2 months data available but i need to show it for all months with empty data blank(value 0);
I tries it but need to add filter for each country..

```
for(var i = 1; i<=12; i++){
if(typeof checkArray[i] == 'undefined'){
  if(i<10) i='0'+i;
  $scope.year.push({
    'month':'2015-'+i,
    'val':'0'
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a nice way to do it just in angular, but I don't know it. So, the javascript hack:

```
<!-- in index.html -->
      <td ng-repeat="month in getMonths()">
        {{getCountryData(selectedCountry, month, 'val')}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="month in getMonths()">
        {{getCountryData(selectedCountry, month, 'val2')}}
      </td>
```

and

```
// in script.js
  $scope.getMonths = function() {
    return ["2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04",
            "2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08",
            "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12"];
  };

  $scope.getCountryData = function(country, month, val) {
    var data = $scope.year.filter(function(el) {
      return el.country == country && el.month == month;
    })
    return data.length == 1 && data[0][val] || 0;
  };
```

This will manually filter your data by month and country. I think this was the intended behaviour, but I might be wrong, since I did not understand what exactly your custom filter was doing. Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7oRFHy5HFcXl4p1Uv1r9?p=preview

Comment: This javacsript hack is good but there are some more additional values i need to show see the html(additional tr td commented) and $scope.years updated array,  http://plnkr.co/edit/5W9Nt0xr9jfJdDHUU9m5?p=preview

Comment: I have update the plunker with new req... please see the bug, same values are keep coming for "val2"  plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5W9Nt0xr9jfJdDHUU9m5?p=preview

Comment: You was almost there, I have updated the post and plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7oRFHy5HFcXl4p1Uv1r9?p=preview

Comment: The thing which i don't understand in html about (val) parameter {{getCountryData(selectedCountry, month, 'val')}}why 'val' why not only only val?

Comment: Because in your html/angularjs there is no variable named `val`. Thus, you pass a string that the function `getCountryData` uses as an index to return the right data